# Did I get Lion for free?

Tags: macos, mac

I had downloaded the Lion beta when it was launched about a month ago. It asked me to enter credit card details and all such things, I did it.
When it was launched, I checked for the updates, there were few, it did. I didn't see what it did, I was out.

Now if I check in Software Purchases, it doesn't show anything. How do I check if I am running Lion for real? About page says I am running 10.7!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is to check if you are running the right build. It's just to check that you are not still running the developer preview. Lion is free for developers anyway, so that might be the reason you got it for free.

[image: About this Mac]

Comment: "Lion is free for devs anyway" ??? How do I ask apple nicely that I am a dev and give it free??

Comment: You need to be registered as a Mac developer. Log into developer.apple.com with your membership and it should be there to download.

Comment: No. You paid $99 for a developer account that came with Lion.

Comment: Members of the Mac Developer Program always had free access to the current version of OS X. In Lions case, they simply changed the Beta Version on the App Store to the Final Version for everyone who had downloaded it. This should be true for the server version as well, but I didn't test that.

Comment: @Nate Bird : I did pay $99, for access to other dev goodies, but now I get access to lion - thats extra :)  
For those who already have a dev account, this is "free" as in "free beer" :)

Comment: If I have 20 Macs in my company, If I purchase Lion OS X from app store, I will pay 30$ for how many machines?
  and if I subscribe to Mac OS developer Program, How much is the maximum number of machines where I can install Lion ?